# setting list of headers in httpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring, servlets, http-headers

In my project I am setting headers in servletResponse for each.

example:

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("access-token","32Bxxxxxxxxx");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("username","admin");
```

It's good, but how can I set these headers as a list that should be added in each response? These headers will be stored as constants in application.

- How can I achieve this without having any loops?
- Are there any methods to achieve this?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think so there is any method to add a list of headers to HttpServletResponse. Check all methods present - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: java 8 i am using

Answer (score 0):

You can add them to a `Map` as key and value pairs and set the keys and values of the `Map` as headers.

Answer (score 0):

You are using servlets. And in servlets you should use filters for stuff like this.

Tomcat in example have build in CORS filter. You can extend it and provide your own logic for 'access-token' and 'user'.

- [JEE Filtering Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)
- [Tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter)
- [example](https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring MVC u can use interceptor and add those headers in the interceptors for all responses (u can also ignore for specified responses). Use Map to add multiple headers